# Removing '\t', '\n' and '\r' characters from string

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

The following python 3 code is what i've been using in order to extract text from a stored content request in a database. How would i go about stripping the \r, \t and \n characters from the resultant string. I've tried regular expressions and various other methods but none as yet are succesful.

```
original = sitetextslist[0]

original = str(original)
original = re.sub('\s+', ' ', original)
print(original)
```

The following string, bar linebreaks, is printed out when i execute the above python code:

```
             target="_blank" class="clearnet">Tor Network Status</a> (<a href="https://jlve2y45zacpbz6s.onion/" 
             rel="noreferrer" target="_blank">alt</a>)</li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<li><a href="https://www.privoxy.org/"
             rel="noreferrer" target="_blank"
             class="clearnet">Privoxy</a></li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</ul>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t</ul>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t
             <ul>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<h2>Security &amp; Guides</h2>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<ul>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<li><a
             href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_Eyes" rel="noreferrer" target="_blank" class="clearnet">5 Eyes
             (info)</a></li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<li><a href="https://www.bleachbit.org/" rel="noreferrer" target="_blank"
             class="clearnet">Bleachbit</a><!-- <span class="error" title="Blocks certain Tor exit nodes
             completely! Be careful! (01/05/19)">Tor-Block!</span>--></li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<li><a
             href="http://bv4saxizrmqmtqpz55bdsxlle2brn46kx7gvnneh7qgs267ii3s3vbid.onion
             /viewtopic.php?f=150&t=89829" target="blank">The Official BV4 Whonix Guide</a></li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t
             <li><a href="http://world.std.com/~reinhold/diceware.html" rel="noreferrer" target="_blank"
             class="clearnet">Diceware: Secure Passphrases</a></li>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<li
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Stripping as removing?

```
target = original.replace('\t', '').replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '')
```

Comment: You don't need to remove all whitespaces but squash them into a single space.